# How to change Row name into Column name in sql server 2008r2

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, xtrareport

I have a trouble to make an XtraCharts Line Diagram (XY Diagram) in asp.net using Stored procedure as binding.

I want to make the `X` value by `R250`, `R500`, `R1000`, `R2000` rows
and `Y` value are the data that already stored in each Row above.

I have an origin table like this:

```
========================================================
No | Sequence No | ItemId | R250 | R500 | R1000 | R2000
========================================================
1    001           118       23     13     14      24
```

I want to display it into

```
========================================================
No | Sequence No | ItemID | Value | NameX
========================================================
1    001            118      23     R250
1    001            118      13     R500
1    001            118      14     R1000
1    001            118      24     R2000
```

Is there any posible query to achieve that?? Thank you so much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` isspecially for this  :

```
select t.No, t.[Sequence No], t.ItemID, tt.*
from table t cross apply
     ( values ([R250], 'R250'),
              ([R500], 'R500'),
              ([R1000],'R1000'),
              ([R2000],'R2000')
     ) tt (Value, NameX);
```

Comment: it works perfectly for me. Thx for the answer bro :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is simple `UNPIVOT` ([helpful article](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)).

Try below code:

```
declare @tbl table (No int, SequenceNo varchar(3), ItemId int, R250 int, R500 int, R1000 int, R2000 int);
insert into @tbl values (1,'001', 118, 23, 13, 14, 24);

select * from (
    select * from @tbl
) p unpivot (
    [Value] for NameX in (R250, R500, R1000, R2000)
) as up;
```